# select giving wrong values

Tags: jquery, html, select

I am creating a data entry form for a school. The school will be entering data in this database for their 5th till 12th grade students. Now 5th grade has 4 sections and all other grade has 3 sections. 10th grade has only one section.

The form is ready and using jquery i am able to make the section select element either show or hide depending on the grade the user selects. My problem is when the user selects std as 5th the section select element is shown and the user selects say "A" and submits. But the value i get is 0. If the user selects section as "D" , the value being sent is "B".

The section select for all other grades are working fine, this problem arises only when the grade selected is 5th.

**Script**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#std").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(parseInt(value)==0) {
           $("#sec5").hide();
           $("#sec6").hide();
        }
        if(parseInt(value)==5) {
            $("#sec5").show();
            $("#sec6").hide();
        }
        if(parseInt(value)==6) {
           $("#sec5").hide();
           $("#sec6").show();
        }
        if(parseInt(value)==7) {
           $("#sec5").hide();
           $("#sec6").show();
        } 
    if(parseInt(value)==6) {
       $("#sec5").hide();
       $("#sec6").show();
    }
    if(parseInt(value)==8) {
       $("#sec5").hide();
       $("#sec6").show();
    }
    if(parseInt(value)==9) {
       $("#sec5").hide();
       $("#sec6").show();
    }
    if(parseInt(value)==10) {
       $("#sec5").hide();
       $("#sec6").hide();
    }
    if(parseInt(value)==11) {
       $("#sec5").hide();
       $("#sec6").show();
    }
    if(parseInt(value)==12) {
       $("#sec5").hide();
       $("#sec6").show();
    }
});

});//]]> 
</script>
```

**HTML Part**

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>DBMS</legend>
      <label for="roll">Roll:
        <input name="roll" type="text" id="roll" value="" size="8" maxlength="10" />
      </label>
      &nbsp;
      <label for="marks">Total Marks:
        <input name="marks" type="text" id="marks" value="" size="3" maxlength="3" />
      </label>
      &nbsp;
      <label for="std">Std</label>
      <select id="std" name="std">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
      <span id="sec5" class="hide">
      &nbsp;
      <label for="sec">Section</label>
      <select id="sec" name="sec">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="A">Sec A</option>
        <option value="B">Sec B</option>
        <option value="C">Sec C</option>
        <option value="D">Sec D</option>
      </select>
      </span> <span id="sec6" class="hide">
      &nbsp;
      <label for="sec">Section</label>
      <select id="sec" name="sec">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="A">Sec A</option>
        <option value="B">Sec B</option>
        <option value="C">Sec C</option>
      </select>
      </span>
      <p align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="nlogin" id="nlogin" value="Submit" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="reset" name="nreset" id="nreset" value="Reset" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: could you make a Fiddle for better understanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `show()` or `hide()` one area of the form, it isn't removed -- just hidden from sight. So your form is actually submitting two select dropdowns with the name (and ID -- a big no-no) of `sec`. Your problem is caused by the second select's value overwriting the first.

It's possible to solve this by `remove()`ing one of the dropdowns, but that wouldn't be reversible and I wouldn't recommend it.

Instead, you might change the name/ID of at least one of those select dropdowns -- say, `sec1` and `sec2` -- and add some server-side code to see which one should be processed.

A second solution might be to just have one select in your HTML and use jQuery to modify its options. This will require rewriting most of your JavaScript code, but it will eliminate the need for server-side coding. (However, server-side validation is ALWAYS a good idea in these cases, as a redundancy, and should be implemented anyway.) Something like:

```
<select id="sec" name="sec">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option id="sec-a" value="A">Sec A</option>
    <option id="sec-b" value="B">Sec B</option>
    <option id="sec-c" value="C">Sec C</option>
    <option id="sec-d" value="D">Sec D</option>
  </select>
```

JS:

```
$("#std").change(function() {
    var v = parseInt($(this).val(), 10); // always use a radix
    if(v==0) {
        $('#sec').hide();
    } else if(v==5) {
        $('#sec').show();
        $('#sec-d').hide();
    } else if(v==6) {
        $('#sec').show();
        $('#sec-d').show();
    }  // etc.
```

Comment: or just have 1 `sec` and hide option D when std!=5

Comment: using 1 sec and hiding the option won't really solve the problem. coz then the select will always be there on the form irrespective of the grade the User selects. @dnagirl

Comment: @RickRoy: if the user can only see sections appropriate to the grade they've chosen, and your back-end validation makes sure that only appropriate choices are acceptable, how does it matter?  I'd say it's better to have 1 incorrect option showing if javascript is disabled than to have an entirely superfluous select box show up.

Comment: ya that's true still it kind of makes it look silly. i got it working by changing the name of the select elements and adding some server side scripts but now for some reason i am unable to enter data for std 6,7,8,9,11,12. However it works fine for 5th and 10th grade

Answer (score 1):

Here is just the minified version of the code:

```
$("#std").change(function() {
      var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);
      $("#sec5").hide();
      if (value == 0 || value == 10) {
           $("#sec6").hide();
      } else {
           $("#sec6").show();
      }
})
```

---

You can change the `name` attribute of the visible select element, and remove the hidden one on form submission:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   $('select').filter(':hidden').remove();
   $('select:eq(1)').attr('name', 'theChosenOne') // if the second select is visible
})
```

Comment: If you're calling `$("#sec5").hide()` in both the `if` and the `else` blocks you may as well move it outside entirely and only have it written once.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use case

   switch (value) {
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
             $("#sec5").hide();
             $("#sec6").show();   break;
   }
2. Double if

   if(parseInt(value)==6) {